# Problem with include and problem RTE project updater

Tags: include

I am doing a project for the university using onsemi (for RSL10) and I have 2 problems.

One of the two problem is with the include: I can't understand why the program cannot find the .h file located in the same folder [error include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMn9Q.png)

Then the second one: when I open the program, an alert comes out with "RTE project updater has encountered a problem" and "Error updating RTE project". If I go into the folder in order to find the error, I find it in a file .h :
[error RTE project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpSSy.png).

Would anyone know how to recommend something to solve?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question that the .h header was not found. If you are using eclipse make sure the path is in the include folder. Also some times eclipse marks some lines as error but they are not compilation error. Do you get any error when you compile your project?

For the second error, I think it is an eclipse error in the workspace. I had the same problem and I deleted my project form the workspace and the import it again. It was resolved.